# Best way to maintain the application hostname and port for a Node.js app

Tags: node.js, web-applications

I have a very simple Node js app, which listens to a particular host ip address and portnumber. 
Right now I am maintaining this hostname and port number in a js file ( called config.js) inside functions .
When I create server I call those functions ,and they return the hardcoded hostname and the port values, using which I create server and listen to it .

so if hostname and port changes, I have to go the config.js and simply changes it .
However I feel, this is not good.
What is the best practice to maintain host and port, and how we generally maintain it for large node apps. Looking for some informations on this

Thanks & Warm Regards
Musaffir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple easy way would be to maintain it in package.json file like

"host": "11.12.13.114",
  "port":"3333",

can require this to the js file where you want the value

const package = require("./package.json");

console.log(package.host) --> 11.12.13.114

Answer (score 0):

There is a npm package called config that you can use to store configurations,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/config, this is a highly used package to manage configurations in multiple environments.

You can use this to have multiple configurations that can be set by an Environment variable and in a dockerized enviroment use docker specific environment variables using custom-environment-variables.js to override default.js.

For more details 
https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/

Answer (score 0):

i think that you should put your hostname and post to env variables.
for dev, use can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv to develop.

e.g.

```
HOST_NAME=xxxx
PORT=3000
```

in your code you can get value via `process.env.HOST_NAME` and `process.env.PORT`